# Record ID not returning from list

Tags: apex, list

I recently posted a question regarding preventing a null list exception ([Link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237067/using-a-formula-to-fetch-a-record-in-controller-test-class-issue)), which was answered but doesn't seem to return a result.

Using the suggested solution, I have updated my controller, keeping the original method I was using. The intended result (aRec.id) is to be used later in a wrapper, however the aRec.Id isn't populating. I added the values to a VF page as a test:

VF Page

```
{!aRec.id} - Returns nothing
{!accountingMonth.id} - Returns Id
```

CONTROLLER

```
public with sharing class ReconcileInvoicesController {

public Accounting_Month__c aRec {get;set;}
public Accounting_Month__c accountingMonth {get;set;}

public List<Accounting_Month__c> amList {get;set;}   

public ReconcileInvoicesController() {

    accountingMonth = [SELECT id FROM Accounting_Month__c WHERE name = :currentRecord.zAccountingMonth__c LIMIT 1];

    amList = [SELECT id FROM Accounting_Month__c WHERE name = :currentRecord.zAccountingMonth__c LIMIT 1];

        Accounting_Month__c aRec;

        if(amList.size()>0) {
            aRec = amList.get(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have declared `aRec` twice and that the one declared locally in your constructor is taking precedence.

You need to remove the `aRec` declaration from constructor, the one just before where you are checking the size of the list.

Additionally your original issue still seems to be there, you also need to remove `accountingMonth` and use a list out there.

Comment: Jeez that was quick! Thanks Jayant, that was the issue. With accountingMonth, I just left that there for testing/reference, it will be removed.